# What is the name of the following cable?

Tags: connector, wire, cables

Instead of wrapping cables I will like to make the connection by using the following type of cable:

[image]

what is the name of the female and male cable with this circular end? I will like to buy this type of cable so that I can connect and disconnect cables in an easier way. Without the name I cannot seem to find it on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are "barrel plug" for the male end, and "barrel socket" for the female end, both sometimes called "barrel jack". Make sure to measure both the outer and inner diameters with calipers since they come in many, many sizes (with 5.5/2.5mm and 5.5/2.1mm probably being the most common).

Comment: There is sometimes variation of the length of the exposed metal barrel from tip to beginning of the overmolded plastic. A barrel plug with a relatively short length may be fine for some applications and not work well for other cases where the barrel has to extend through the thickness of the plastic housing on a product to engage the barrel socket on circuit board inside.

Comment: Sometimes also called a DC power plug, often found on Laptop chargers these days in some very peculiar variants as well with 3 connections.